# What kind of low-cost equipment do I need to learn and experiment with RADAR at home?

Tags: education, research, radar

I am interested in RADARs. However, I don't have enough time to go to school for studying RADARs. Therefore, I am thinking about self-study.

What kind of low-cost equipment do I need to learn and experiment with RADAR technology at my home?

Comment: You'll probably need a license from a regulator authority because radar can interfere with other radio wave users such as airlines and the military.

Comment: Not sure what specific aspects of radar you want to explore, but there are more harmless technologies that work by bouncing stuff off other stuff (sonar, lidar) and work with arduinos and similar cheap low voltage home technology.  Maybe that already would provide some insights for you?